# Single Responsibility and Dependency Injection possible in Actors model?

Tags: dependency-injection, akka, guice, actor, single-responsibility-principle

What are good and established dependency injection practices in Akka, when you have

1. dynamically created actors and
2. some singletone bean(service or http client) to be injected in some dynamically created acator?

**What I want to avoid**

- Adding to one actor any extra responsibility of creating other actors
- Storing some Injector field to perform injection later, after creation.
- Creating collaborators (injected services) in one actor for another.

**What I want to be able to do**

- be able to decorate injected services using DI container, not explicitly wrapping them in decorator during creation.

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: May be at least there is a specific solution to case where actors (A and B) are singletons?
Then ActorB can be Injected into ActorA by guice?
Not the case for pure ActorRef - type can not be infered, but may be there are parametrized ActorRefs which can be subject to smart DI?

Comment: Are you looking for a DI solution because the project is hard to move away from DI? Or is it fine? Just want some clarification before I propose a non-DI solution.

Comment: @YikSanChan I am looking for DI solution because I want my classes to be unit testable.
To be unit testable - I want them not to have any responsibility except their only responsibility. And here, storing Injector or creating other Actors and providing needed collaborators for those actors - are all extra responsibilities which makes unit testing harder, now I need to test other responsibilities which otherwise would be taken by DI. But I would still be happy to see what you are going to suggest.

Comment: If the aim is testability, then I'd suggest that `ActorRef` is the ultimate in DI and for testability you just inject your own actors that behave as you'd like.